# Primality test for numbers of the form $N=2 \cdot 6^n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, primality-test

Can someone provide counterexample, if one exists, to the claim given below?

Inspired by [Lucas-Lehmer primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) I have formulated the following claim:

> Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot((x-\sqrt{x^2-4})^m+(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})^m)$ . Let $N= 2 \cdot 6^{n}+1 $ where $n\ge3$ . Let $S_i=S_{i-1}^6-6S_{i-1}^4+9S_{i-1}^2-2$ with $S_0=P_{18}(12)$ . Then, if $S_{n-2} \equiv 0 \pmod{N}$ then $N$ is prime .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdi7EOAiEQRHs-46rFw-hiQkzW_QSvobcQMZDcAbkjGv_ebWys5s1kXuETqYntzt3KiKS8YKtzSPH-2VJ8AZ4NGqdJhb4y0jvlOYLwhcveGs_X-oA_xYnhD1abSZM8R0bR8xM889G0NZcOg8QSB_2roS6tbrnLpOkLqxcsqA==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Note that $P_m(x)=2T_m \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$, where $T_m(x)$ is mth [Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#First_kind). Also , note that $S_i=P_6(S_{i-1})$ .

I was searching for counterexample using the following PARI/GP code:

```
CE261(n1,n2)=
{
for(n=n1,n2,
N=2*6^n+1;
S=2*polchebyshev(18,1,6);
ctr=1;
while(ctr<=n-2,
S=Mod(2*polchebyshev(6,1,S/2),N);
ctr+=1);
if(S==0 && !ispseudoprime(N),print("n="n)))
}
```

I have tested this claim for all $n$ up to $10000$ and there were no counterexamples.

Python script that implements this test can be found [here](https://github.com/PedjaTerzic/T261).

Comment: The proof of Lucas-Lehmer seems to work, by considering the $6 \pm \sqrt{35}$... up to a certain point, because we show that the element ($\omega$) satisfies $\omega^{6^n}=-1$ (in a suitable extension of a $\mathbb{F}_q$,$q | N$). But we can’t conclude that the order of $\omega$ is $N-1$ (which entails that $N-1|q^2-1$ by Lagrange, and we should be able to conclude somewhat similarly to LL), because it could be $2^{n+1}$ without contradicting the properties we know.

Comment: Anyway, the same kind of reasoning implies that if $q$ is a prime divisor of $N$, then $2^{n+1}$ divides $q^2-1$, thus $2^n$ divides $q-1$ or $q+1$ thus $q \geq 2^n-1$. As a consequence, $N$ must have at most two prime divisors, counting multiplicities.

Comment: are prime if $6^n$ is not of form $2ab+a+b$ which makes a maximum variable size of under $\sqrt{3\cdot 6^{n-1}}$

Comment: Why invent a new test when we can just use the well known BLS75 tests which have multiple implementations?